# Video Capture : Frame always empty - opencv

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, video

I am working with openCV Version 2.4.9, and on Mac OSX. 
I have written this code for loading and displaying a video on my desktop. But it never seems to work. I always get the output as "frame empty". Thus it does not complain about reading the video using VideoCapture.It is NOT able to capture any frames, and thus 'frame' is always EMPTY. Any idea what the problem might be?
Note: I have tried both ways to capture a frame - commented as try 1 and try2.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Mat frame;
    VideoCapture capture_ir("/Users/shreyatandon/Desktop/resize_ir.avi");


    if ( !capture_ir.isOpened() )  // if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    for (;;){
       // capture_ir.read(frame); //try1
          capture_ir>>frame;       //try2
        if(frame.empty()){
            std::cerr<<"frame is empty"<<std::endl;
            break;
        }
        imshow("", frame);

        waitKey(10);

            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know in windows your file paths wouldnt work they would need to be \\ instead of /. I don't know if this is the case for Mac

Comment: If the path was wrong, it would give me the output as ' Cannot open the file'. But thankyou anyway!
It is / for mac .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just made it work.

```
Mat current_frame;
VideoCapture video("video.avi");
while(true)
{
    video.read(current_frame);
    imshow("Image",current_frame);
}
```

If you keep having problems using avi format have a look at your links to the ffmpeg libraries and it dependencies. I tried to install it from scratch using homebrew and it is working without problems. Cheers